# Relation not set in a One to Many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Boot 2, Spring Data with Hibernate implementation.
Database used is Postgres

I try to save `CarServices` with it's child `CarComponentOccurrences`:

```
@Entity
public class CarServices{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carService", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<CarComponentOccurrences> carComponentOccurrences;

}


@Entity
public class CarComponentOccurrences {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private CarComponents carComponent;

    @ManyToOne
    private CarServices carService;

}
```

`CarComponentOccurrences` is saved but in db `CarComponents` and `CarService` is null.

In `CarComponentOccurrences`, `CarComponents` and `CarService` is set.

Edit:

In my service layer

```
@Autowired
private CarServicesRepository repository;

public void save(){
    CarServices cs = new CarServices();
    cs.setName("name");

    List<CarComponentOccurrences> carComponentOccurrences = new ArrayList<>();

    CarComponentOccurrences cco = new CarComponentOccurrences();
    Optional<CarComponents> optCarComponents =carComponentsRepository.findById(1);
    if (optCarComponents.isPresent()) {
        cco.setCarComponentOccurrences(optCarComponents.get());
    }

    cco.CarServices(cs);

    carComponentOccurrences.add(cco);
    cs.setCarComponentOccurrences(carComponentOccurrences);

    repository.save(cs);
}
```

Edit 2

```
CREATE TABLE car_component_occurrences
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  ...
  car_component_id integer,
  car_service_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT car_component_occurrences_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fka4fmpytg0s9a94377pdw5ssib FOREIGN KEY (car_service_id)
      REFERENCES car_services (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fko85tjs5s6f1o9u7kkk152d147 FOREIGN KEY (car_component_id)
      REFERENCES car_components (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Edit 3

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('public.car_component_occurrences_id_seq')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        public.car_component_occurrences
        ( car_component_id, car_service_id, name, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    update
        public.car_services 
    set
        name=?,
    where
        id=?
```

Comment: try to add the entire method in which you set-up and save the entities

Comment: ok i updated the post

Comment: so where is the actual save / persist called? on Session or EntityManager etc.

Comment: i added code for the save i use spring security save...

Comment: so its only the foreign keys that are not set? Is CarService persited?

Comment: CarService, CarComponentOccurrences are persistend, but in CarComponentOccurrences, foerign key are not

Comment: what are the actual column names of those foreign keys?

Comment: car_component_id  
car_service_id

Comment: why not state the SQL INSERT statements issued by your JPA provider? aka debugging

Comment: it's done, select, insert and update..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

In `CarServices`:

- cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST  -> PERSIST, MERGE

In `CarComponentOccurrences`:

- @ManyToOne private CarComponents carComponent; -> @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The reason is as follows: You persist a CarServices. Now, for Hibernate to cascade any of the persist operations, this must be annotated with a non-breaking chain of objects, i.e. CarServices -> CarComponentOccurrences -> CarComponents. Missing cascade on @ManyToOne leads to CarComponents not being persisted. Persist chain with PERSIST only does, in my experience, generally not work with Collections, although it is curious that CarService did not get persisted in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If your column names in db are `car_component_id` and `car_service_id` then you should use the `@JoinColumn` annotation in order to override the defaults of the persistence provider, which is expecting: `carcomponent_id` and `carservice_id` (if the primary keys of those referenced entities are named `id`) respectively.

Reference from [JoinColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name()):

> Default (only applies if a single join column is used): The
>   concatenation of the following: the name of the referencing
>   relationship property or field of the referencing entity or embeddable
>   class; `"_"`; the name of the referenced primary key column.

Comment: Done this modification but nothing have changed, same issue.